# Integrations done by residues and numericals don't agree

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, complex

I want to integrate

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dw \hspace{0.51em}\frac{w^{n} e^{i wt}}{(w^{2}-\Omega^{2})^2 +(\gamma w)^2}
$$

I did so using contour integration because it has the poles:

$$w=\mp \frac{i\gamma}{2} \pm \sqrt{\Omega^{2}-\frac{\gamma^{2}}{4}}$$

resulting in:

$$2^{1-n} i \pi \left(\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} \tau  \left(\gamma +i \sqrt{4\Omega ^2-\gamma ^2}\right)} \left(-\sqrt{4 \Omega ^2-\gamma^2}+i \gamma \right)^n}{\gamma  \left(\sqrt{4 \Omega ^2-\gamma^2}-i \gamma \right)+4 i \Omega ^2}-\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2} i \tau \left(\sqrt{4 \Omega ^2-\gamma ^2}+i \gamma \right)}\left(\sqrt{4 \Omega ^2-\gamma ^2}+i \gamma \right)^n}{\gamma \left(\sqrt{4 \Omega^2-\gamma ^2}+i \gamma \right)-4 i \Omega^2}\right)$$

I decided that I wanted to check with the numerical results because I hadn't done contour integration in a while, for that I did the following, I chose $ n = 3, \gamma = 3, \Omega = 4 $, and plotted for $ \tau $

```
f[n_, γ_, Ω_, τ_] := I 2^(1 - n) Pi((E^(-(1/2) τ (γ + I Sqrt[
 -γ^2 + 4 Ω^2])) (I γ - Sqrt[-γ^2 
 + 4 Ω^2])^n)/(4 I Ω^2 + γ (-I γ + Sqrt[-γ^2 
 + 4 Ω^2])) - (E^(1/2 I τ (I γ + Sqrt[-γ^2 + 4 Ω^2])) 
(I γ + Sqrt[-γ^2 + 4 Ω^2])^n)/(-4 I Ω^2 + γ 
(I γ + Sqrt[-γ^2 + 4 Ω^2])))
Plot[f[3, 3, 4, τ], {τ, 0, 5}]
```

and then tried the same with numerical integration

```
int[n_, γ_, Ω_, τ_] := γ w^n Exp[I w τ]/((w^2 - 
Ω^2)^2 + (γ w)^2)
fau[τ_] := NIntegrate[Im[int[3, 3, 4, τ]], {w, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Plot[fau[τ], {τ, 0, 5}]
fau[τ_] := NIntegrate[Re[int[3, 3, 4, τ]], {w, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Plot[fau[τ], {τ, 0, 5}]
```

However the obtained results are quite different, so my main question is is it possible that numerical algorithms suffer with these kind of integrals making them divergent when they're not?

Comment: For $n = 3$, your integrand scales asymptotically as $e^{iwt}/w$.  I wouldn't expect that to be convergent.

Comment: Also, is the $\Omega$ in the denominator of your integrand supposed to be squared?

Comment: it is supposed to be squared sorry about that

Comment: I mean I maybe deeply confused but $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{iwt}/w dw $$ converges, it's proportional to the sign function (inverse fourier transform of 1/w )

Comment: The Fourier transform of the sign function is not strictly well-defined as an integral;  you have to use some kind of limiting procedure to get it, or view it as a distribution, which `NIntegrate` cannot do.  There's some discussion of this problem [over on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726611/fourier-transform-of-signum-function/3726819).

Comment: It is conditionally convergent, behaving like the alternating harmonic series (-1)^n/n. I would not b e surprised if `NIntegrate` has troubles with it.

Comment: thanks Michael,  also thanks Daniel  any tips on checking the answer you get from residues in this kind of situation? Is there any trick or numerical routine that would help out?  I thought about excluding the poles of the function from  the integration, unsure about how to do it in Mathematica though

Comment: @DanielLichblau: `NIntegrate` should crack such integrals. Here is a simpler example : `Integrate[Exp[I*w]*w/(w^2 + a^2), {w, -Infinity, Infinity},   Assumptions -> a > 0]` results in `I E^-a \[Pi]` in accordance with `NIntegrate[Exp[I*w]*w/(w^2 + 1), {w, -Infinity, Infinity}]` which produces `0. + 1.15573 I`

Comment: @user64494 not the right kind of integral, the simpler example would be:

NIntegrate[Exp[I*w]*w/(w^2 - 1)^2, {w, -Infinity, Infinity}]

which NIntegrate actually has troubles with at least a lot of warnings are fired

Comment: @GerardoSuares: The integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac { e^{iw}w} {(w^2-1)^2} \, dw $$ diverges even as its principal value.

Comment: @user64494 The problem was solved with your answer all I needed to do was including  AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4, Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory" in NIntegrate, would you mind telling me how you knew you should include them ?

Comment: @GerardoSuares: From the documentation (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly found the poles. See the output of

```
ToRadicals[Solve[((w^2 - \[CapitalOmega]^2)^2 + (\[Gamma] w)^2) == 0, w, 
Assumptions -> \[CapitalOmega] > 0 && \[Gamma] > 0], 
Assumptions -> \[CapitalOmega] > 0 && \[Gamma] > 0]
```

Here is its part

> $$ w\to \fbox{$i \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \frac{1}{2} \left(-\gamma -\sqrt{\gamma ^2-4 \Omega ^2}\right) & \gamma >0\land 0<\Omega \leq \frac{\gamma }{2} \\
>  \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{\gamma ^2-4 \Omega ^2}-\gamma \right) & \gamma >0\land \Omega =\frac{\gamma }{2} \\
>  \text{Root}\left[\Omega ^4+\text{$\#$1}^4+\left(2 \Omega ^2-\gamma ^2\right) \text{$\#$1}^2\&,1\right] & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\text{ if }\gamma >2 \Omega $}$$

The symbolic integration

```
n = 3; \[CapitalOmega] = 4; \[Gamma] = 3; \[Tau] = 1; 
Integrate[w^n Exp[I *
 w *\[Tau]]/((w^2 - \[CapitalOmega]^2)^2 + (\[Gamma] w)^2), {w,-\Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> `(E^(-I Sqrt[ 1/2 (23 - 3 I Sqrt[55])]) (-23 +  3 I Sqrt[55] + (23 + 3 I Sqrt[55]) E^( 1/2 I (Sqrt[46 - 6 I Sqrt[55]] + Sqrt[ 46 + 6 I Sqrt[55]]))) \[Pi])/(6 Sqrt[55])`

`N[%]`

> `8.88178*10^-16 - 0.980392 I`

is in accordance with

```
NIntegrate[w^n Exp[I * w *\[Tau]]/((w^2 - \[CapitalOmega]^2)^2 + (\[Gamma] w)^2),
{w, \-Infinity, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
 Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"]
```

> `0. - 0.980372 I`

Comment: I did have a typo because I wrote $\frac{\gamma}{4}$ instead of $\frac{\gamma}{2}$ but it was right in the code, my bad just edited the question

Comment: @GerardoSuares: Your mistakes are more serious than a typo.

Comment: @GerardoSuares: I think four (even three) parameters are too many for `Integrate` in this case.

Comment: The integral was found by residue integration rather than using Integrate, and actually no, it was just the typo 


once I added AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
 Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory" to NIntegrate the answers agree N[f[3, 3, 4, 1]] gives -2.94118 I while NIntegrate gives -2.94112 I (Including the gamma meaning 3*- 0.980372 I)

would you mind telling me how you knew you should include those? and thanks I already marked your answer as correct